# Extract array from varchar in PrestoSQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a VARCHAR field like this:

```
[
  {
    "config": 0,
    "type": "0
  },
  {
    "config": x,
    "type": "1"
  },
  {
    "config": "",
    "type": ""
  },
  {
    "config": [
      {
        "address": {},
        "category": "",
        "merchant": {
          "data": [
            10,12,23
          ],
          "file": 0
        },
        "range_id": 1,
        "shop_id_info": null
      }
    ],
    "type": "new"
  }
]
```

And I need to extract merchant data from this. Desirable output is:

10

12

23

Please advise. I keep getting Cannot cast VARCHAR to array/unnest type VARCHAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using json path `$.*.config.*.merchant.data.*` but if it does not work for you (as for me in Athena version, where arrays in json path are not supported well) you can cast your json to `ARRAY(JSON)` and do some manipultaions from there (needed to fix your JSON a little bit):

Test data:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
        (JSON '[
  {
    "config": {},
    "type": "0"
  },
  {
    "config": "x",
    "type": "1"
  },
  {
    "config": "",
    "type": ""
  },
  {
    "config": [
      {
        "address": {},
        "category": "",
        "merchant": {
          "data": [
            10,12,23
          ],
          "file": 0
        },
        "range_id": 1,
        "shop_id_info": null
      }
    ],
    "type": "new"
  }
]')
        
 ) AS t (json_value))
```

And query:

```
SELECT flatten(
    transform(
        flatten(
            transform(
                CAST(json_value AS ARRAY(JSON))
                , json_object -> try(CAST(json_extract(json_object, '$.config') AS ARRAY(JSON))))),
        json_config -> CAST(json_extract(json_config, '$.merchant.data') as ARRAY(INTEGER))))
FROM dataset
```

Which will give you array of numbers:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [10, 12, 23] |

And from there you can continue with unnest and so on if needed.

Comment: @itsmethubui was glad to help!